# Convergence of $g_k(x) = \Big{(} \frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt{k}} \Big{)} \cos(kx)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, trigonometric-series

From *“Elementary Classical Analysis*. (marsden, hoffman)

> Let $g_k(x) = \Big{(} \frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt{k}} \Big{)} \cos(kx)$ on $\mathbb{R}$.
>
> Does the series $\sum g_k $ converge pointwise or uniformly.

Graphically, this seems to converge (at least pointwise) to something. I think I need a trig identity to get an upper bound for the series, I can't think of one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The series does not converge when $x =\pi$ since $\cos (k \pi)=(-1)^{k}$ and $\sum \frac 1 {\sqrt k}$ is divergent.

Comment: But is $\sum (-1)^k/\sqrt{k}$ divergent? I know the sequence isn't by the alternating series test

Comment: @Jess $(-1)^{k} (-1)^{k} =+1$ so the series becomes just $\sum \frac 1 {\sqrt k}$

Comment: I see, of course.